# Reshape function in matlab and images

Tags: matlab, reshape

My question is about the 'reshape' function in matlab. Myself and some researchers made a byte counter for images (tiff, .JPEG etc) for research interests. We then sent the results to another anonymous party for review. The upshot of this was being told the counter we had produced was wrong and apparently the matlab function reshape should have been used. The suggested code is below. What I do not understand is what this function does to an image! I have run the code but...I do not understand what the code is doing to the image and what the output data is.

If anyone would clarify this for me and give me an explanation for dummies I would be very thankful!

```
clc,    clear,  close   all;

IM  =   imread('Images  for Dataset 2/DS2-11.jpg');

hist(reshape(IM,1,[]),0:255);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to

```
IM=IM(:);

hist(IM,0:255); %note that now histogram is recommended, instead of hist
```

This basically makes a 1D vector from your image, and the computes an histogram of it, using 0:255 bins. The code `reshape(IM,1,[])` means: reshape `IM` so its first dimension is size 1 and the second is "whatever you need to fit it ([])".

Example: `size(IM)` is 200x500. The reshape function will give a vector that is 1x100000.

I believe the version I showed is clearer code.

---

**NOTES**: that histogram will work if, and only if:

1. Your image is uint8 type
2. it is a grayscale image, thus, doesn't have RGB channels

If the image is double, then your data will be in [0-1] range so binning 0:255 wont really work.

If the image is RGB you are going to count the 3 color channels "together" and that will probably distort your research results.

Comment: Thank you, this is beginning to make sense..One follow up question if I may: what do each of the values in the bins represent?

Comment: @Rbicknel Glad it helped. Consider accepting it as an asnwer. Also, you may want to read what a histogram is, specially *before* you use one. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram